# PHP sanitization question

Tags: php, sanitization

Is it safe if I just use htmlpurifier for some of my user submitted data so they can enter html code like myspace?

http://htmlpurifier.org/

Here is a sample code of PHP and htmlpurifier.

```
$purifier->purify($content);
```

Comment: Safe from what?  HTML injection?

Comment: from malicious user submitted data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is pretty much safe and that's what HTMLPurifier is handy at amongst other things.

> HTML Purifier is a standards-compliant
>   HTML filter library written in    PHP.
>   HTML Purifier will not only remove all
>   **malicious    code (better known as
>   XSS**) with a thoroughly audited,
>   secure yet permissive whitelist,   it
>   will also make sure your documents are
>   standards compliant, something only
>   achievable with a    comprehensive
>   knowledge of W3C's specifications.

Answer (score 0):

yes, I haven't heard that it's broken , up to now.